# Permissions of newly created directories

Tags: 16.04, server, permissions, directory

In my workplace we have a server running Ubuntu, where many of us do data analysis on. Since we're often working on the same data, everyone usually has access to all files and directories. Nevertheless, we sometimes have problems working in each other's directories.
There is at least one colleague (who is in exactly the same user groups and has the same rights that I have) who automatically creates directories which are readable and executable for everyone, but in which only the owner can write. When I create a new directory, also all users in my group can write to it - which is what we want.

I would like to figure out why some (or most) people on our server automatically create directories with the right permissions, while others don't, but I don't even know where to start looking. Can someone explain this, or let me know what to search for, please?

**Edit** based on comments
`ls -ld <directory>` gives me `drwxr-xr-x 2 user users 12288 Jan 11 11:03 test`

We usually access the server with ssh, either with MobaXterm or virtual Ubuntu machines on Windows. Directories are created with `mkdir` on the command line.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -ld /PATH/TO/DIRECTORY`, replacing the directory argument with the path to the directory that is not writeable for you?

Comment: Could you also explain how the users perform access (windows-based computers to ubuntu samba file-server, terminal access,...)

Comment: Long story short - depending on what exactly you might be interested in in some particular scenarios - what might be interesting for you (some short directions, keywords...):  umask, sgid on the directories and, of course, proper group memberships (which you already do in some way). In some more complicated scenarios ACLs may also be helpful - but I wouldn't be too hasty to go this way, unless the standard Unix/Linux access mechanisms aren't exhausted - not to overcomplicate access/permissions management. Anyway - if you have some reading about umask and sgid - that may give you some ideas.